# ARKit + Core location - points are not fixed on the same places

Tags: ios, core-location, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm working on developing iOS AR application using ARKit + Core location. And the points which are displayed on the map using coordinates move from place to place when I go. But I need they are displayed on the same place.
Here you can see the example of what I mean:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DQkTJFc9aChtGrgPJSziZVMgJYXyH9Da/view?usp=sharing

Could you help to handle with this issue? How can I have fixed places for points using coordinates? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Please keep the link intact when asking the questions through this kind of links.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you attach objects to planes. However, when you move the ARKit extends the existing planes. As a result if you put points, for example, at the center of the plane, then the center is always updated. You need to recalculate the coordinates of the point and place objects correctly.

The alternative is not to add objects to planes (or in relation to them). If you need to "put" object on a plane, then the best way is to wait, until the plane will be directed enough (it will not change his direction significantly if you will move), then select a point on the plane where you want to put your object, then convert this point coordinate to global coordinates (as a result if plane will change his size the coordinate you have will not be changed at all), and finally put object in root (or another object that it's not related to the plane).